# Hide .php extension on website title

Tags: php, html, css

Hello I tried to configured my Title on my website. My idea is, any page needs to read the command "include header.php" and automatically update the website title.
I found that script but I can't hide .php extension.

Any ideia?

```
<title>
<?php

$current_file_name = basename($PHP_SELF);
echo $current_file_name."\n"


?> | Site Name</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array of all the goodies you need. In this case, you're looking for the 'filename'.

```
<?php
$parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
print_r($parts);
```

You can use this as so:

```
<?php
$parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
echo "<title>{$parts['filename']}</title>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want but if you want to remove the string `.php` in your string `$current_file_name`, you can replace it with `""` with `str_replace` :

```
<title>
<?php

$current_file_name = basename($PHP_SELF); // = "header.php"
$current_file_name = str_replace(".php", "", $current_file_name); // = "header"
echo $current_file_name."\n";


?> | Site Name</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide .php extension using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```